# prove network is truly unavailable

Tags: networking, foxpro

I have an old school foxpro web app that I am trying to help limp along while I rewrite the system.  Every day, multiple times, I get this following error message: *The specified network name is no longer available*.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to troubleshoot this?  Perhaps, prove to my IT guys that there really is a network issue.  I have theories, but I have no idea how to prove anything, it always comes back to foxpro sucks rewrite it now.

I'll take any help, tools, and will answer any questions that may clarify this for you.

thanks

Comment: Since you did not specify, is the IP address dynamic, if so, then have you not considered that it could possibly be a DHCP lease time is much shorter than you think? My thinking is that the lease is up and hence 'The specified network name is no longer available' when it is trying to renew the ip address after a period of time...

Comment: I do know that we use ip reservations, so the ip never changes.  Not sure if there is still a lease and whether the theory holds under those conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider writing a small program that pings the network resource periodically. You might just look for a file and if the network is failing and the program cannot find the file email the folks in charge of the network and yourself. This would be an independent app, and best if not written in FoxPro so you can independently prove it is not the application or the language/tool it was written in.

I have seen this when networks have bad wiring, a bad port on the switch/hub, a failing NIC in the mix, and sometimes when the network is just flooded with requests from workstations.

You also did not mention if this was a wireless connection. I am hoping not, but I have seen wireless (especially slower wireless) hubs fail with respect to the network overload and slow and unreliable performance. Especially compared to a wired network.

Rick Schummer

Comment: we have a tool that checks for a file on the server periodically, it doesn't seem to catch the error since the disconnect is fairly short lived.  the foxpro holds the file open, which I guess I could write a program to prove this in c#.

Answer (score 2):

We have a very large multi-user VFP application on hundreds of sites. Occasionally you get this sort of problem. It is almost always down to environmental issues.

Had one just recently where a client had two machines continually crashing out of the VFP application. Network IT guys swearing up and down that it's not their problem. But what's this in the System Log of both machines? Why, it's the Broadcom NIC reporting a network link loss detected at the same times the application crashed.

Check if the client and server NICs in your situation can report this.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments about IP address, is the setting on the network controller to be energy efficient? and thus turn itself off when not actively in use.

Comment: Where do I check that?

Also, I get this error message all the time?

The time provider NtpClient is configured to acquire time from one or more time sources, however none of the sources are currently accessible.  No attempt to contact a source will be made for 15 minutes. NtpClient has no source of accurate time.

Comment: Bring up the properties of your network controller (where it displays your IP status, duration, etc.  Click on "Properties".  Then, to the right of the label of your network card, click "Configure".  There should be a tab for "Power Management", and a checkbox there to allow device to turn off to save power... uncheck it.  Additionally, the "Advanced" tab will have properties and one such as "Wake Up Capabilities".  Just some stuff to look at.

Comment: i don't appear to have that option.  perhaps not a problem on win2k3 and hyper-v?